# How do I create dynamic php routes with my route class? (php)

Tags: php, url-routing

I want to make a link to go to a url that is dynamically made, but I don't know how to do this with my code. Here is my Router class `

```
class Router
{
    public $routes = [
        'GET' => [],
        'POST' => []
    ];

    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static;

        require $file;

        return $router;
    }

    public function get($uri, $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['GET'][$uri] = $controller;
    }

    public function post($uri, $controller)
    {
        $this->routes['POST'][$uri] = $controller;
    }

    public function direct($uri, $requestType)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes[$requestType])) {
            return $this->routes[$requestType][$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
    }
}
```

and here is my routes page

```
<?php

$router->get('', 'controllers/index.php');

$router->get('message', 'controllers/message.php');

$router->get('loginForm', 'controllers/loginForm.php');

$router->get('register', 'controllers/register.php');
```

on my page with my html I put an  link with a dynamic link `href='displayPost<?php echo $image->id; ?>`  but I'm not sure how to add that $image->id; part into my router list and class to make dynamic url's.

Comment: Your regret this later on when you want to implement nested routes i.e `/message/123/reply` etc. Save yourself the hassle and use something like [fat-free framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/routing-engine#ReST:RepresentationalStateTransfer), which you could just use the router.

Comment: I'm just building a small project to teach myself php and I don't plan on using nested routes. I just want to know how to do this with my routes class for now. @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Check out my repo https://github.com/JozefCipa/microfw/blob/master/app/Support/Router.php if you want. I solved exact same thing once

Comment: @JozefCipa I'm learning php right now and I'm unsure which of your functions makes a dynamic route url possible. Could you point it out to me?

Comment: It's all happening in `start` function. It gets current URL, parses it and checks for given handler (function) in `$routes` array, that's same as in your code.

Comment: @JozefCipa  I'm not sure how to use the start function on my routes page though and how to send parameters that make it dynamic? Do I just wrap the start function in my $router-get('dsfsd', 'sdfsdf') page?

Comment: Check out `index.php`, `$router->start();` is called there. And then you just define your routes in `app/routes.php` file